# How do I assign a numeric value to a picklist text value and multiply by a number field?

Tags: formula, picklist

I have a picklist with 4 text values. I want to assign a numeric value to each text value. I then want to multiply the chosen value by a number field.

Can anyone help me with the syntax?

1. Picklist field = Plan_object__c
2. Number Field = R_Complex__c
3. Picklist Values = Low,High,Medium,None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your custom formula field (type Number)

```
R_Complex__c * 
CASE (Plan_Object__c,
          "Low",1,
          "Medium",2,
          "High",3,
          "None",0,
          NULL)
```

where the values of 1,2,3 for low/medium/high are illustrative only

Comment: Not sure how your answer is different from mine other than giving him the exact answer, isn't the point to help them learn and not do it for them?

Comment: perhaps -- in your answer, you copied straight from the Success page from a 2006 post and the copy included merge field syntax which for formula fields is not required (which is how I interpreted the question).  I think when I answered this I was coming off a long threaded convo where I realized I needed to be more explicit and so was primed for explicitness when I got here. That said, I certainly agree that OP should have tried something first before I answered.

Comment: Gotcha, fixed the example to be a more recent example!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Case with your picklist field, take a look at this formula example [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas_oppty_mgmt.htm&language=en_US):

```
    CASE(StageName,
"Prospecting", "Insert 1st Document ID",
"Qualification", "Insert 2nd Document ID",
"Needs Analysis", "Insert 3rd Document ID",
"Value Proposition", ...
)
```

In this example the result is text but you would instead assign a numeric value assigned based on the choices and then multiply the results by your `R_Complex__c` numeric field.